# Difference between Serializable and non Serializable object save into database

Tags: database, object, dns, save, serializable

What is the different between when saving data object in to database when object is serializable or not serializable.

Ex : I have a domain class called Book

```
class Book implements Serializable{
private int id;
private String name;
//getter and setter
}
```

without implements Serializable interface

```
class Book {
private int id;
private String name;
//getter and setter
}
```

Now I'm going to store Book object into database table. 
I know for a fact the when implementing Serializable, data should be convert into byte stream. So what is the difference between above two options when saving data into db

Can anyone correct me
Thank you
Amila

Answer (score 2):

In general, no difference at all.  having an entity as `Serializable` for persistence is not a must, and strictly depends on the framework which you are using for your persistence layer.

e.g. Hibernate does not require at all, though it is a best practice to make entities `Serializable`, as per JPA specification -

> If an entity instance is to be passed by value as a detached object
>   (e.g., through a remote interface), the entity class must implement
>   the Serializable interface.

So if you need detached entity for example in HTTP session, or to pass to another layer, Serialize them, etc - you need to have your entities as `Serializable`objects.